# Synthax of firstly in PromiseKit 6

Tags: ios, swift, promisekit

I would like to use this method from PromiseKit but dont know how to write propper synthax :x

```
public func firstly<U: Thenable>(execute body: () throws -> U) -> Promise<U.T> {
do {
    let rp = Promise<U.T>(.pending)
    try body().pipe(to: rp.box.seal)
    return rp
} catch {
    return Promise(error: error)
}
```

}

```
 firstly {
           return someMethodWhichReturnsPromise()
        }.then{
    }
 ...
```

How can I invoke this?
Code is from: https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Sources/firstly.swift

Answer (score 0):

A basic example of [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) "firstly" usage:

```
func someMethodWhichReturnsPromise() -> Promise<Int> {

    // return promise
}

firstly {

    someMethodWhichReturnsPromise()

}.then {

    // Execute more logic here after 'firstly' block completes

}.catch {

    // handle error if you need to
    handle(error: $0)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunetley it is not this because it invokes method which wants to use Guranatee. I need to use method which uses Thenable

Comment: Can you provide a code sample with what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Marlen Assuming your "someMethodWhichReturnsPromise()" is valid the above should work. Maybe take remove your "return" as well.

Comment: func add(a:Int, b:Int) -> Promise<Int> {
        
        return Promise { seal in
            if a > b {
                seal.fulfill(2)
            } else {
                seal.reject(NSError(domain: "aa", code: 43, userInfo: nil))
            }
            
        }
    } 
Like this